# Problem with reading html text from Google Translator

Tags: r, rvest, translate, cjk

I am having issues **scraping** some text from Google Translate when I translate something from Japanese to English. This is the code I'm using:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url_pr2 <- 'https://warp.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/11454275/www.mofa.go.jp/mofaj/press/release/17/rls_0430b.html'
webpage2 <- read_html(url_pr2, encoding = 'utf8')
title_data <- html_nodes(webpage2,'h2')
title <- html_text(title_data)
getParam = title
translateFrom = "ja"
translateTo = "en"
search <- gsub(" ", "%20", getParam)
URL_title <- paste("https://translate.google.pl/m?hl=",translateFrom,"&sl=",translateFrom,"&tl=",translateTo,"&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=",search,sep="")
page <- getURL(URL_title)
web_title <- read_html(URL_title)
text_final <- html_nodes(web_title,'.result-container')
html_text(text_final)
```

But I get the following text:

[1] "æ Š € è ¡ “Å” å Š ›ã «é – ¢ ã ™ ã ‹æ— ¥ æ œ¬å ›½æ” ¿ åºœã ¨ã ل‘ ã ‡³ åºœã ¨ã ®é – “ã ®å” å®šã ®ç½²å"

If I run the same code but with something translated from Spanish or French to English, it works perfectly. This is another code:

```
url_pr2 <- 'https://www.gob.mx/sre/prensa/la-sre-brinda-asistencia-a-mexicano-detenido-en-letonia?idiom=es'
webpage2 <- read_html(url_pr2, encoding = 'utf8')
title_data <- html_nodes(webpage2,'.bottom-buffer')
title <- html_text(title_data)
getParam = title
translateFrom = "es"
translateTo = "en"
search <- gsub(" ", "%20", getParam)
URL_title <- paste("https://translate.google.pl/m?hl=",translateFrom,"&sl=",translateFrom,"&tl=",translateTo,"&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=",search,sep="")
page <- getURL(URL_title)
web_title <- read_html(URL_title)
text_final <- html_nodes(web_title,'.result-container')
html_text(text_final)
```

From the previous code I get the following result:

[1] "The SRE provides assistance to a Mexican detained in Latvia"

Does anyone know how to extract the English translation? If I go to the google translate website I generate, I can see the English translation.

Comment: Where is `getURL` func?

Comment: I'm sorry! I forgot to add this. It's from the RCurl package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly encode the entire phrase to translate

```
search <- URLencode(getParam)
```

---

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url_pr2 <- 'https://warp.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/11454275/www.mofa.go.jp/mofaj/press/release/17/rls_0430b.html'
webpage2 <- read_html(url_pr2, encoding = 'utf8')
title_data <- html_nodes(webpage2,'h2')
title <- html_text(title_data)
getParam = title
translateFrom = "ja"
translateTo = "en"
search <- URLencode(getParam)
URL_title <- paste("https://translate.google.pl/m?hl=",translateFrom,"&sl=",translateFrom,"&tl=",translateTo,"&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=",search,sep="")
page <- read_html(URL_title)
text_final  <- html_node(page,'.result-container') %>% html_text()
print(text_final)
```

`"Signing of an agreement between the Government of Japan and the Government of the Islamic Republic of Pakistan on technical cooperation"`

Comment: Thank you @QHarr! This is super useful.